# Kubernetes HPA kills random pod during scale down | anyway to avoid killing a random pod rather go for pod with low utilization

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, devops, autoscaling

I have deployed HPA to monitor the Memory and CPU, our application is not robust enough to handle the failures where it terminates the tasks when pod crashed or killed during scaledown, and needs manual intervention restart the tasks with dataloss and need lot of effort. I am looking around if there is a way to send a trigger a command send and receive before triggering a kill signal. I see prestop hook but not sure how exactly i can get this worked. Is it possible to trigger the prestop hook before sending the kill signal during scale down, where run a script in pod by monitoring and send back the signal to kubernetes when CPU or mem hits certain number and then kubernetes sends kill signal to initiate shutdown process. Any help/suggestions.?

```
NAME                                      REFERENCE                             TARGETS             MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/hpa   Deployment/task-deployment1   545%/85%, 1%/75%            2         5         5          36h
```

below is the hpa manifest file

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: hpa
  namespace: namespace-CapAm
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: task-deployment1
  minReplicas: 2
  maxReplicas: 5
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 75
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: memory
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 85
```

We won't be able to use promotheus as it is not firm supported and we were suggested to use HPA with Mem and CPU only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HPA does not kill (delete) the Pod, it scales the Deployment, which in turn scales underlying ReplicaSet. So the Pod deletion isbtriggered by RS scale change. This makes the.process unaware if the scaling was.in any way related to HPA. You should write your app in a way that is ok with deletion of any Pod in deployment and make it handle normal shutdown gracefully.

Comment: Thanks, this answers one of my question. My application is not robust to handle the tasks during pod deletion. any other suggestions.? I am trying to implement prestop hook and kill the pod from inside (2/2 container).

Comment: For future reference, there is a [proposal](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/pull/3190) tackling selective scale down behaviour